# Barycentric coordinates of a tetrahedron

Tags: c++, coordinates, tetrahedra

I would like to ask for help regarding barycentric coordinates of a tetrahedron:

Following an approach I found here:
 http://www.cdsimpson.net/2014/10/barycentric-coordinates.html
i implemented a C++ function for finding barycentric coordinates of a point in a tetrahedron:

```
float ScTP(const Vec &a, const Vec &b, const Vec &c)
{
    // computes scalar triple product
    return Dot(a, Cross(b, c));
}

Vec4f bary_tet(Vec3f a, Vec3f b, Vec3f c, Vec3f d, Vec3f p)
{
    float va, vb, vc, vd, v;
    Vec3f vap = p - a;
    Vec3f vbp = p - b;
    Vec3f vcp = p - c;
    Vec3f vdp = p - d;

    Vec3f vab = b - a;
    Vec3f vac = c - a;
    Vec3f vad = d - a;

    Vec3f vbc = c - b;
    Vec3f vbd = d - b;
    // ScTP computes the scalar triple product
    va = ScTP(vbp, vbd, vbc) * 1 / 6;
    vb = ScTP(vap, vac, vad) * 1 / 6;
    vc = ScTP(vap, vad, vab) * 1 / 6;
    vd = ScTP(vap, vab, vac) * 1 / 6;
    v = 1 / ScTP(vab, vac, vad) * 1 / 6;
    return Vec4f(va*v, vb*v, vc*v, vd*v);
}
```

However, my code seems to calculate slightly wrong barycentric coordinates - 
comparing my results with a reference implementation from here:
http://dennis2society.de/painless-tetrahedral-barycentric-mapping
my four barycentric values are each smaller the values calculated by
the reference implementation.

Does anyone spot any error in my implementation? Many thanks for help!

Comment: how much smaller? Couldn't it be just `float` vs `double` precision? (didn't run your code, as it looks not very complete, `ScTP` looks missing) (also you shouldn't copy input parameters like this... use `const Vec3f & a` rather, if the performance is important (probably is, because otherwise why would you use `float` instead of `double`)

Comment: unfortunately not, my values are roughly 1/40 smaller..

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i did not yet look for speed, but i will add it for the final implementation. also I added the ScTP function to the code

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think "v" may be written other way you intended. You want (1/6)*ScTP and that to flip? But you do 1/ScTP and then /6 further. Btw, you can simply drop all the 1/6 if I didn't lost all my math skills completely, if you use only va/v, ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blind guess:

```
Vec4f bary_tet(const Vec3f & a, const Vec3f & b, const Vec3f & c, const Vec3f & d, const Vec3f & p)
{
    Vec3f vap = p - a;
    Vec3f vbp = p - b;

    Vec3f vab = b - a;
    Vec3f vac = c - a;
    Vec3f vad = d - a;

    Vec3f vbc = c - b;
    Vec3f vbd = d - b;
    // ScTP computes the scalar triple product
    float va6 = ScTP(vbp, vbd, vbc);
    float vb6 = ScTP(vap, vac, vad);
    float vc6 = ScTP(vap, vad, vab);
    float vd6 = ScTP(vap, vab, vac);
    float v6 = 1 / ScTP(vab, vac, vad);
    return Vec4f(va6*v6, vb6*v6, vc6*v6, vd6*v6);
}
```

Comment: many thanks, your version works!! and i understand the error in my code.