# Determine if we can obtain a target color by mixing colors from a list

Tags: java, python, arrays, algorithm

Given a list of colors(RGB values) L and a color C, determine if we can mix 2 or more colors from the list  L to obtain C. The colors from the list can be mixed in any proportion.

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is not a code writing service (nor is it a homework help service). *You* must write a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help with a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can visualize the RGB values as points in 3D space. The problem then becomes whether you can express the RGB value of your target color as an interpolation between other points in the color space.

An ideal way to do this is by using [Barycentric co-ordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system), with the condition that the co-ordinates (i.e. the mixing proportions) add to 1. So, you need to go through your list and find a set of 2 to 4 points that form a line, triangle or tetrahedron simplex that encloses your target point. The cartesian co-ordinates of a point (in this case, the RGB values) can be calculated as a linear combination of the simplex points with the barycentric co-ordinates as co-efficients, so the [barycentric co-ordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545520/barycentric-coordinates-of-a-tetrahedron) of the point will be your mixing proportions. The point needs to be inside the simplex, or else you will end up with proportions that aren't in the range of 0-1, which I assume is invalid.

If you have a large list of points and you want to find out if a valid set of mixing proportions exists, compute the convex hull of all the points and check if your target point lies inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using rectilinear transformation of coordination compression. Visualize it as a 3d space and then combine three points to get to the target color. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Sahil, it would be great if you can add some more explanation. Hoping for more help.